# Jquery conditional drop down list based on attributes

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I need to Show / Hide options of select list based on the value of a first select list but I can't use the value of the second one I need to use data attributes or something else, I try this from a snippet I found that works fine on values but it seems that I misuse the data method

I Show you my Html and js :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var optarray = $("#group").children('option').map(function() {
        return {
            "data": this.data,
            "option": "<option data='" + this.data + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
        }
    })
        
    $("#type").change(function() {
        $("#group").children('option').remove();
        var addoptarr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
            if (optarray[i].data.indexOf($(this).data()) > -1) {
                addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
            }
        }
        $("#group").html(addoptarr.join(''))
    }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="">Choose a Type</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="art">Art</option>
    <option value="cook">Cook</option>
</select>

<select name="group" id="group">
    <option value="">Choose a group</option>
    <option value="band" data="music">Band</option> 
    <option value="guitarplayer" data="music">Guitar Player</option> 
    <option value="painter" data="art">Painter</option>
    <option value="graffer" data="art">Graffeur</option>
    <option value="chief" data="cook">Chief</option>
</select>
```

Thx guys (and girls (:)

Comment: suggest you start by reading the API docs for `jQuery.data()`. Usage is wrong in markup as well as `this.data` and `this.text` are undefined. `this` will be a DOM element. Using your console to look a errors will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `"data": $(this).attr("data")` for `"data": this.data,` ; chaining `.get()` to `.map()` to return array instead of jQuery object ; substituting `i = 1` for `i = 0` at `for` initialization , to remove `option` not having value `<option value="">Choose a Type</option>` from being iterated ; within `for` statement substituting `.indexOf($(this).val())` for `.indexOf($(this).data())`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var optarray = $("#group").children('option').map(function() {
        return {
            "data": $(this).attr("data"),
            "option": "<option data='" + $(this).attr("data") + "'>" + this.textContent + "</option>"
        }
    }).get();
        
    $("#type").change(function(e) {
        $("#group").children("option").remove();
        var addoptarr = [];
        for (i = 1; i < optarray.length; i++) {
         console.log(optarray[i].data, optarray[i].option)
            if (optarray[i].data.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
            }
        }
      console.log(addoptarr)
        $("#user_job_title_str").html(addoptarr.join(""))
    }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="">Choose a Type</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="art">Art</option>
    <option value="cook">Cook</option>
</select>

<select name="group" id="group">
    <option value="">Choose a group</option>
    <option value="band" data="music">Band</option> 
    <option value="guitarplayer" data="music">Guitar Player</option> 
    <option value="painter" data="art">Painter</option>
    <option value="graffer" data="art">Graffeur</option>
    <option value="chief" data="cook">Chief</option>
</select>

<select id="user_job_title_str"></select>
```

Comment: Thx a lot , I knew I was misusing the data options